# Mysql query like query dosent send accurate result in join with where condition from others table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables users and user groups.

I am running folowing query:-

```
SELECT `u`.`id`, `u`.`fname`, `u`.`lname`, `u`.`customer_id`, `u`.`email`, `u`.`partner_id`, `u`.`campaign_promocode`, `u`.`utm_medium`, `u`.`referrral_source`, `u`.`is_active`, `u`.`created_at`, `ug`.`group_id`
FROM (`users` as u)
JOIN `users_groups` as ug ON `ug`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
WHERE `ug`.`group_id` =  '99'
OR `ug`.`group_id` =  '100'
AND `u`.`is_active` IN ('1', '2') 
AND  `u`.`fname`  LIKE '%sandeep%'
ORDER BY `u`.`id` desc
LIMIT 10
```

but the above query is returning wrong result if i remove in where clause `ug`.`group_id` =  '99'
    OR `ug`.`group_id` =  '100' then i am getting right.

The database has approx 7K rows.

Comment: Well we don't know what you want do we ?!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `u`.`id`, `u`.`fname`, `u`.`lname`, `u`.`customer_id`, `u`.`email`, `u`.`partner_id`, `u`.`campaign_promocode`, `u`.`utm_medium`, `u`.`referrral_source`, `u`.`is_active`, `u`.`created_at`, `ug`.`group_id`
FROM (`users` as u)
JOIN `users_groups` as ug ON `ug`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
WHERE (`ug`.`group_id` =  '99' OR `ug`.`group_id` =  '100' )
AND `u`.`is_active` IN ('1', '2') 
AND  `u`.`fname`  LIKE '%sandeep%'
ORDER BY `u`.`id` desc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: put or condition round brackets.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i got result. but why my query wasn't work?

Comment: @SandeepSahu If you don't put brackets then OR considers the whole other part of the Query as operand, for the right results you have to give it right operands with correct syntax.

Comment: because or condition was not in brecket

Comment: @RishiPrakash thanks for explaining. I have to this keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE `ug`.`group_id` =  '99'
OR `ug`.`group_id` =  '100'
```

is different from

```
WHERE (`ug`.`group_id` =  '99'
OR `ug`.`group_id` =  '100')
```

change where clause to latter.

If you don't put brackets then OR considers the whole other part of the Query as operand, for the right results you have to give it right operands with correct syntax.